# Cannot find duplicates in array

Tags: c#

I need to find duplicate numbers in this method. Ive tried this, but i think im missing something. anyone can see what I'm doing wrong.

---

```
 public bool FindDublicate(int[] a)
    {
         bool svar = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {

            for (int j = i; j < a.Length - 1; j++)
            {
                if (a[j] == a[j + 1])
                {
                    svar = true;
                }
                else return false;
            }
        }
        return svar;
    }
```

Comment: @Mayank Actually its not, that question is comparing *two* arrays. This is looking for duplicates in a single array.

Comment: You are comparing each element only to the next one up, so in e.g. (0, 1, 0) your code would not catch the two zeroes as being duplicates. You want to compare `a[i]` to `a[j]`.

Comment: Your logic is wrong at the line

   **else return false;**

whenever a single duplicate is not found, it does not mean that, there is no duplicate.

Comment: Thanks @500-InternalServerError, i just missed that

Comment: I know @RatulSharker, i removed that, the only thing i missed is if (a[j] == a[j + 1]) to be changed with [i]

Comment: I think your method will also return true if there are no duplicates since you default the value of `svar` to true.  It will also default to true if your array is empty.

Answer (score 7):

If you are only interested in knowing whether your array contains duplicate or not you can do:

```
return a.Distinct().Count() != a.Length;
```

Comment: This will return true, if there are not duplicates.

Comment: @CriketerOnSO Your code is wrong, he wants to find duplicates so you would want `!=` rather than `==`.

Comment: Thanks Habib and @Greg. Modified the condition.